# How to Remove Favorites from Navigation Pane in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Is there an easy way to remove favorites from the navigation pane in Windows 8 without editing the registry?

Comment: Note for down-voters: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @techie007 Agree, but no upvotes for the question either, just for the answer.

Comment: @moab The OP had originally put that in the question, so I moved it to a comment. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the favorites from the navigation pane, just right-click the navigation pane and you will find an option to remove it:

[image]

**This option was not present in Windows 7.**